# What's the translation of "record-tying" in French?

Tags: traduction, sport

[Example](https://mmajunkie.usatoday.com/2022/11/ufc-fight-night-214-marina-rodriguez-amanda-lemos-weigh-in-results-live-video-stream) of use:

> Weigh-in results: A record-tying four misses.

What's the translation of "record-tying"  in French? Does any French adjective convey that meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Résultats à/de la pesée officielle : quatre (pésées) ratées, égalant
> la marque/le record pour un tournoi.

---

L'adjectif [*identique*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/identique) :

> Résultats à/de la pesée officielle : quatre (pésées) ratées, marque/nombre *identique* au record dans un tournoi.

Comment: *Pesées officielles : Quatre poids hors limites, record égalé.*

Comment: @jlliagre Tu devrais produire ça comme réponse, c'est probablement meilleur...

Comment: Je n'ai fait que changer l'ordre de ta réponse. L'idée y était déjà: "**égalant le record**" → "**record égalé**"

Answer (score 2):

Un « réaménagement » des éléments d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51843/26366), qui se rapproche davantage de la morphologie de « record-tying » :

> Pesées officielles : Quatre poids hors limites, **record égalé**.
> [jlliagre]